# Access to ioreg using Python?

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth

Is there a way to access the values `ioreg` utility accesses via Python?

What i'm looking is to add monitoring of the battery status of my Magic Mouse. I know I can get it by using

```
ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l | grep -E '"Product"|BatteryPercent'
```

So -- what's the magic to get the value of BatteryPercent into Python, without launching `ioreg` via `subprocess`?

Answer (score 2):

The ioreg utility uses IOKit to get the values for for example the battery status of the Magic Mouse.

You can access IOKit from Python using ctypes - a foreign function library for Python. It allows you to call C/Objective C functions etc. from Python.

You can see an example of how to that with IOKit here:

https://github.com/pudquick/pypmset/blob/master/pypmset.py

In addition you'll find that someone already creeated a wrapper for IOKit to be accessible from Python here:

https://github.com/mosen/moobjc-framework-IOKit

Comment: Thanks. Will check them out. I found first link, but failed come up with the working code yet.